# Is there a code difference between vanilla PHP and Microsoft's version?

Tags: php, iis

I'm about to install PHP on a Windows Server 2012 with IIS 8.0. I was going to download from windows.php.net as I've done before. However, I noticed MS has their site up at http://php.iis.net/

Are these two sites offering the same thing, or has MS modified the code in their PHP offering? I'd like to stay with pure PHP if they're offering a different build.

Anyone have any experience with the MS offering?

Comment: I'm quite partial to believe that they are the same version, the Microsoft flavor might contain different files to assist with IIS/PHP Configuration, but having used both. I can't see no noticeable difference. But i'm quite intrigued if there is any difference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it is the same PHP. You can see the official php.net documentation on IIS installs here:

http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.iis7.php

You can even build or install the PHP you want and connect it to IIS manually (so it would be the same PHP you get anywhere else). Using the MS installer, could they have tampered with PHP? Yes. Did they? I seriously doubt it.

One major difference is the extensions available on IIS. Like how they offer Windows Cache instead of APC. I believe pretty much all pecl extensions work however.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.wincache.php

So you may find a quite different ecosystem of extensions but the core language looks to be exactly the same.

Comment: Thanks, Daniel. Good info.